# How to check what is inside an input textbox in Adobe Flash CS5.5

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am making a game with multiple levels in flash and I want to have it where each level has its own 4 digit code, which can be used to return to that level.

I have created an input textbox, and a button. If I want it to run the command:

```
gotoAndStop(3);
```

How would I do this? I know that I need to place the following first:

```
on (release) {

}
```

So how would I make an if statement to check my textbox, and goto a frame when the button is pushed & the code is correct?

Comment: Is this actionscript 2 or actionscrip 3?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've given your text input an instance name (for my example let's says its `txtCode`,  and you have a submit/go/check code type button and that's where the below `on (release)` method is, you would do something like this:

```
on (release){
    //parseInt converts the text to a number. this will effectively trim the white space and ignore any trailing letters
    switch(parseInt(txtCode.text)){
        case 1234:  
            //if the code entered was 1234, go to frame 3
            gotoAndStop(3);
            break;

        case 1235:
            //if the code entered was 1235, go to frame 4
            gotoAndStop(4);
            break;

        default:
            //what to do when it doesn't match anything
            gotoAndStop(1);
    }
}
```